# Does it matter if an entity for a JPA Repository is defined in another gradle project for Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I currently have the following situation. I have, next to others, two projects of interest. I have a project called `authlib` which contains a lot of data classes and a class to perform web requests to my second project of interest, let's call it `server`.

The first project is meant to be used as a library to facilitate web requests to the `server` project. `server` is a Spring Boot project made with Java and it has a `implementation` relation to `authlib`, meaning that the classes in `authlib` are available in the server, but not the other way round. This is unfortunate, since the class that makes all the api requests to the `server` lives in the `authlib` and I cannot use the database entities directly. This shows, because there seem to be already some duplicate classes, where my predecessors have needed data from the server but weren't able to use the correct classes. Instead, they created a "light" version of the entities they needed and created a parsing method in the server to just return this light version of the data class, when returning something in the controller.

My Entities in the `server` project look something like this:

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MinecraftAccountRank {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 40)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String pexGroup;
    private String displayName;
    private String discordRole;
    private String discordPrefix;
    private String teamspeakRole;

    private int rankOrder = 0;

}
```

Note the includes. I am not using any spring specific annotations from spring boot. I therefore thought it must be possible to move the class to my auth, since the repositories and every use of my entity classes could then just use the import from the `authlib`. This shouldn't make any difference... should it?

This is where I got first doubts and began to question if there were any side effects I just didn't see. Firstly, the `authlib` project is entirely written in Kotlin, which I usually wouldn't consider a problem and which would just save me the lombok annotations. Also, I could just add `javax.persistence` to the authlib.

In total I have two questions:

- Will my project using Kotlin be bothered by my java class just exisiting there? If so, are there any side effects to be expected when I translate my entity code to Kotlin?
- Do I have to expect any other drawbacks from moving my entity class to another project? My `server` project is at the end of the dependency chain and is itself not a dependency to any other project (that I know of). Will there be a problem with my `JPARepository` classes when the entity is coming from a library?